# CSADMIN has the create/change function disabled

Tags: sap-gui, sap-basis, netweaver

I have recently installed the SAP ABAP 7.51 trial system to try to configure the content repository.

However when I am accessing the newly installed system using SAP GUI using SAP* (or DEVELOPER) user account
[image]

and open CSADMIN or OAC0 transactions the Create/Change buttons are disabled on the toolbar and I also cannot edit any of the existing content repositories.

Am I missing any permissions? How can I check for those?

PS: I'm not trying to set up SAP content server, we're going to use third-party one.

Comment: Access the client 001, not the client 000. Note that 7.50 is an old version, more recent trials are available (7.52, 1909)

Comment: NB: I don't think that the trial is provided with the SAP Content Server, I doubt that you can make it work (CSADMIN), but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm accessing using client 001 and SAP* user [screenshot1](https://imgur.com/a/b18b1rb)
Still the buttons are not available in OAC0 [screenshot2](https://imgur.com/a/hO9oyrm)

Comment: PS: I'm not trying to set up SAP content server, we're going to use third-party one. I'm just not able to add/edit content servers at all in SAP.

Comment: Okay. I just meant that I think CSADMIN is for SAP Content Server. Using OAC0 for third-party content server should be fine .

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I seem to be stupid - in order to be able to edit content repos I first needed to click Display/Change button (Ctrl+F4). Then the Create option became available.